How is the Joule-Thomson coefficient related to the increase in temperature of the valve connecting bike pump to tire after pumping?
I was watching this lecture about enthalpy from a thermodynamics course (MIT OCW, 5.60, lecturer Moungi Bawendi).
The lecturer goes through experiments and calculations to determine the coefficients (ie the partial derivatives) in the differential form
$$dH=\left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right )_P dT+\left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right )_T dP$$
in terms of things we can measure.
A constant pressure process gives us $\left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right )_P=C_P$ which is experimentally determined.
The other partial derivative, $\left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right )_T$ can be obtained with the Joule-Thomson experiment.
This experiment is devised so that the enthalpy of the system is constant.
$$dH=C_PdT+\left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right )_T dP=0$$
$$\implies \left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right )_T=-C_P\left (\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right )_H=-C_P\mu_{JT}$$
where $\mu_{JT}$ is the Joule-Thomson coefficient, an experimentally determined coefficient.
An example of $\mu_{JT}\neq 0$ for a real gas is given. Consider pumping a bicycle tire with a pump. The valve going into the tire gets hot.
The temperature of the valve is essentially the same temperature as the air being compressed in the pump. The compression happens fast and we can approximate it as an adiabatic process.
The lecturer says that we are changing the pressure, temperature is going up, and therefore $\mu_{JT}=(\partial T/\partial P)_H>0$.
I don't quite understand. Here is my reasoning, which seems to be incorrect/incomplete.
When we pump, we are compressing air without exchange of heat.
For an adiabatic process we know the relationships between initial and final volumes, pressures, and temperatures.
We know, analytically, that temperature goes up.
From
$$dH=C_PdT-C_P\mu_{JT}dP$$
we know that the first right-hand term is positive. If $dH$ were zero then we would know for sure that $\mu_{JT}$ must be positive.
But is the tire pumping process at constant enthalpy, and is the argument above the one used to conclude that $\mu_{JT}>0$ for air or am I missing something else?

Pumping involves work and enthalpy change.

There are actually two sequential things that are happening in the situation you describe:

Adiabatic compression heating inside the pump.  This is the major effect and occurs even if the gas exhibits behavior identical to that of an ideal gas.

Joule Thomson heating in gas passing through the valve. This is typically a small additional effect resulting from the non-ideal behavior of the gas.  For an ideal gas, the JT coefficient is zero.


The amount of energy lost in heating the valve itself is typically negligible, even though the valve gets hot.
For an ideal gas being compressed slowly and reversibly by the pump, $$\frac{T_1}{T_0}=\left(\frac{P_1}{P_0}\right)^{\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}}$$where $T_0$ and $P_0$ are the initial temperature and pressure in the pump initially, respectively, and $T_1$ and $P_1$ are the temperature and pressure within the pump after some compression, and also the temperature and pressure entering the valve.
For an ideal gas, $T_2=T_1$, where $T_2$ is the gas temperature exiting the valve.  For a non-ideal gas, to a first approximation,$$T_2\approx T_1+\mu(P_1-P_2)$$where $P_2$ is the exit pressure from the valve.
